# Trying to set up default_scope but getting "Support for calling #default_scope without a block is removed" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, associations, parent, default-scope

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  I have these two models

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
    …
    has_one :user
```

and

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :address
  default_scope includes(:address)
```

I want to auto-load my parent association when I load my “MyObject” but I’m getting this error on the “default_scope” line …

```
Support for calling #default_scope without a block is removed. For example instead of `default_scope where(color: 'red')`, please use `default_scope { where(color: 'red') }`. (Alternatively you can just redefine self.default_scope.)
```

How do I adjust my “default_scope” line to auto-load my parent association?

Answer (score 2):

- You are missing block in your line, Change it like this:

  ```
  default_scope { includes(:address) }
  ```

Comment: Although changing my line to "" causes the error to go away, my address entity is still not loaded when I call "User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])".  I have verified there is in fact an address id associated with the user in question.

Comment: I tried same and it worked for me. How are you verifying loading of address with it... e.g. Are you sending result as JSON object ?